# How to split the contents of `$PATH` into distinct lines?

Tags: bash, shell

Suppose `echo $PATH` yields `/first/dir:/second/dir:/third/dir`.

**Question:** How does one echo the contents of `$PATH` one directory at a time as in:

```
$ newcommand $PATH
/first/dir
/second/dir
/third/dir
```

Preferably, I'm trying to figure out how to do this with a `for` loop that issues one instance of `echo` per instance of a directory in `$PATH`.

Answer (score 58):

```
echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n'
```

Should do the trick. This will simply take the output of `echo "$PATH"` and replaces any colon with a newline delimiter.

And if you need it in a loop:

```
for dir in `echo "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n'`; do
    echo "$dir"
done
```

Note that the quotation marks around `$PATH` prevents the collapsing of multiple successive spaces in the output of `$PATH` while still outputting the content of the variable.

Comment: Quote your variable expansions. `"$PATH"`

Comment: The question asked for it to be used in a `for` loop

Comment: @doublesharp He said preferably. I'm giving a solution that is not only for his needs, but also thinking about other people that searches for this in Google / SO.

Comment: @EtanReisner I don't know about you, but I just tested without the `$PATH` quoted and it works just fine.

Comment: @EtanReisner Just tried it. Output is: A(new line)foo bar(new line)B. You can even try it in your browser: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_terminal_online.php

Comment: Bah! HTML stripped my spaces. Put more than one space in between `foo` and `bar` in that variable and try it again. Like [this](http://ideone.com/QsCTKF).

Comment: @EtanReisner I edited the answer. For reference, the spaces are ignored when the variable is not quoted.

Comment: Technically they aren't "ignored" the shell just collapses them during its [field splitting](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) the value of the expanded variable which then means they no longer exist by the time `echo` sees them and can output them to the pipeline (or whatever). The quotes prevent the shell from doing that.

Answer (score 6):

How about this:

```
echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's/:/\n/g'
```

(See [sed's `s` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#The-_0022s_0022-Command); `sed -e 'y/:/\n/'` will also work, and is equivalent to the `tr ":" "\n"` from some other answers.)

It's preferable not to complicate things unless absolutely necessary: a for loop is not needed here. There are other ways to execute a command for each entry in the list, more in line with the [Unix Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_philosophy):

> This is the Unix philosophy: Write programs that do one thing and do it well. Write programs to work together. Write programs to handle text streams, because that is a universal interface.

such as:

```
echo "$PATH" | sed -e 's/:/\n/g' | xargs -n 1 echo
```

This is functionally equivalent to a for-loop iterating over the PATH elements, executing that last `echo` command for each element. The `-n 1` tells `xargs` to supply only 1 argument to it's command; without it we would get the same output as `echo "$PATH" | sed -e 'y/:/ /'`.
Since this uses [`xargs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xargs), which has built-in support to split the input, and echoes the input if no command is given, we can write that as:

```
echo -n "$PATH" | xargs -d ':' -n 1
```

The `-d ':'` tells xargs to use `:` to separate it's input rather than a newline, and the `-n` tells `/bin/echo` to not write a newline, otherwise we end up with a blank trailing line.

Comment: Quote your variable expansions. `"$PATH"`

Comment: The question asked for it to be used in a `for` loop

Comment: @doublesharp It's not hard to loop over a series of strings, though typically you want a `while` loop. https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor

Comment: Not all `sed` dialects interpret `\n` as an escape code for newline.

Answer (score 6):

As an additional option (and in case you need the entries in an array for some other purpose) you can do this with a custom `IFS` and `read -a`:

```
IFS=: read -r -a patharr <<<"$PATH"
printf %s\\n "${patharr[@]}"
```

Or since the question asks for a version with a for loop:

```
for dir in "${patharr[@]}"; do
    echo "$dir"
done
```

Comment: The array + for loop is the only approach that will work for *all* legal `PATH` values (including those with directory names containing newline characters). (It's a limitation of `PATH` that a directory name containing a `:`, though legal, cannot safely be added to `PATH`).

Answer (score 6):

here is another shorter one:

```
echo -e ${PATH//:/\\n}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`tr`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix)) (translate) to replace the colons (`:`) with newlines (`\n`), and then iterate over that in a for loop.

```
directories=$(echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n")
for directory in $directories
do
    echo $directory
done
```

Comment: No reason at all to iterate over your already newline-delimited output. And this won't work for path entries that have spaces (or glob characters) in them.

Comment: @EtanReisner the question specifically asked for it

Comment: Fair enough, I'd glossed over that preference. This still isn't safe for spaces or globs though and means that converting to spaces or `NUL`s would likely be better and then parsing that for the (admittedly `while`) loop.

Answer (score 2):

My idea is to use `echo` and `awk`.

```
echo $PATH | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {for (i=0; i<=NF; i++) print $i}'
```

**EDIT**

This command is better than my former idea.

```
echo "$PATH" | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"; OFS="\n"} {$1=$1; print $0}'
```

Comment: Quote your variable expansions. `"$PATH"`

Comment: Set `OFS="\n"` and awk will do the newline splitting for you. (After you convince it you have modified the line with something like `$1=$1`.)

Answer (score 0):

If you can guarantee that PATH does not contain embedded spaces, you can:

```
for dir in ${PATH//:/ }; do
    echo $dir
done
```

If there are embedded spaces, this will fail badly.

Comment: This also fails with shell globs. `P='A:/bin/*:B'; echo ${P//:/ }`

Answer (score 0):

```
# preserve the existing internal field separator
OLD_IFS=${IFS}
# define the internal field separator to be a colon
IFS=":"
# do what you need to do with $PATH
for DIRECTORY in ${PATH}
do
  echo ${DIRECTORY}
done
# restore the original internal field separator
IFS=${OLD_IFS}
```